# subquery to count number of distinct values of field in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my Query:

```
{ 
runCommand : { 
    aggregate : 'record', 
    pipeline : [ 
        { $match : { "_id" : { "$binary" : "HUjjlL5SCpVKNVnedOk+nQ==", "$type" : "3" } } },
        { 
            $project : { 
                Results : 1,
                ResultCount: {
                    $size: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$Results.Type",
                            cond: { $eq:["$$this", "SpecificResult"] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        { $unwind  : '$Results' }
    ],
    cursor: {}
}
}
```

And here is my Document in MongoDb:

```
{
"_id": Binary("HUjjlL5SCpVKNVnedOk+nQ==", 3),
"Header": {
"FileFormatVersion": "2.0",
"Filename": "1231434534654",
"ReferenceNumber": "235423645677"
},
"Results": [
{
    "Type": "Title",
    "Seq": "1111",
    "Title": "Some Title",
    "SubTitle": "",
    "TitleLevel": "1"
},
{
    "Type": "Title",
    "Seq": "056330010",
    "Title": "Some Subtitle",
    "SubTitle": "",
    "TitleLevel": "2"
},
{
    "Type": "Result",
    "Seq": "0560002200040",
    "ResultValue": "value",
    "ResultComments": "value"
},
 {
    "Type": "SpecificResult",
    "Seq": "0123234010",
    "Title": "",
    "Name": "Name",
    "ResultComments": "Comment1"
},
 {
    "Type": "SpecificResult",
    "Seq": "0123234010",
    "Title": "",
    "Name": "Name222",
    "ResultComments": "Comment1"
},
 {
    "Type": "SpecificResult",
    "Seq": "01234210",
    "Title": "",
    "Name": "Name333",
    "ResultComments": "Comment2"
}
]
}
```

I want to add a subquery to calculate number of results with unique "ResultComments".

In SQL it's looks like: `SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ResultComments) from Results where Type = 'SpecificResult'), (select count (*) from Results where Type = 'SpecificResult') FROM Results;`

How to do that in MongoDb?

Comment: Will adding $group on $Results.ResultComments inside the pipeline serve the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $reduce to get a distinct set of your ResultComments, then use $size to get the array size. (similar to your `ResultCount` field). You can add the `Results.Type == "SpecificResult"` criteria in the $cond too.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RwK2uvtYGaK)

Comment: This query returns unique ResultComments from all records. But I need only when Type = 'SpecificResult'. Look at SQL plz.

Comment: Hi @kostepanych, thanks for your reminder :) I updated the answer and the mongo playground link. You should be able to see the $cond now contains your `Results.Type == "SpecificResult"` criteria. The test case in the new playground are also added with **Comment3** for your testing :)